# Transparent button with Vector Panel Design v11?

Tags: panel, capl, canalyzer

It is possible to configure a transparent button in Vector Panel Design version 11, such that I can see a picture under the button, but can't see the button at all?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the button and choose "Show properties".At the top of properties window, there is a small buton - "Properties". It shows all properties of the button , including "General" - "Is Visible At Runtime".
It may help for your demand.